# how to connect alloydb with cData?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cdata, google-alloydb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8ZH5.png)How to connect alloydb with cData?,
it is either showing connection time out or connection refused while connecting. in Cdata I am doing the basic settings providing the server ,password, user, data base name.
but still also not connecting. I tried the documentation available in GCP to connect a cluster outside its VPC but still also not working.

Comment: I CData compliant with Postgres API?

Comment: I see PostgreSQL listed in the relational section of cData's page, so should be okay on that front. Need more information about what you did/tried to connect from outside the VPC. AlloyDB's private only connectivity makes connection from outside the VPC tricky for sure. If you could, edit your question with details of what you did to try to connect. As well as which documentation you're mentioning in your question too so I can see what you're looking at.

Comment: @GabeWeiss i am trying to connect a vm in alloydb for postgres to c data cloud

Comment: Right, but mechanically, what are you doing? Are you trying to pass the AlloyDB instance's IP address to cData? Are you creating a bastion instance in GCP that runs the AlloyDB proxy and passing the bastion instance's public IP to the cData cloud? AlloyDB doesn't expose public access, so you'd have to do some extra infra in order to try to route traffic to it.

Comment: @GabeWeiss i have vm instance and  passing its external ip address to cdata

Comment: Can you confirm you can connect to the AlloyDB instance from the VM? SSH into the VM, and try connecting to the AlloyDB instance with psql. Could try with the IP directly, or use the proxy, either way should work ok. The VM and the AlloyDB instance are on the same VPC, yes?

Comment: @GabeWeiss yes i can connect to the alloydb instance from VM , and the vm and instance are on same VPC.

Comment: Okay good, baby steps. :D For cData, how do you specify the target database? Is it a specific port it connects on (5432?). A next step to try, would be to start a Postgres database on the VM, and see if you can get cData connecting to that ok. That'll confirm the path from cData to Google Cloud ok. It may also be a firewall issue. Have you changed any of the firewall rules for the VM?